# Using intern with systemjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, intern

I am currently looking into integrating intern into a bigger technology stack and seem to be stuck.
Mostly, I followed [this article on how to test TypeScript with Intern](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/24/testing-typescript-with-intern/).

I develop using nodejs and angular with typescript that gets transpiled to ES5. The module format is *systemjs* (which, unfortunately, is a must-have in this environment).
There is something mentioned of testing other module-types in the intern documentation, but I am not sure how to adapt this to my needs, if possible.

If I try to bypass systemjs by manually `require($module)`, intern keeps informing me that required modules are missing (dependencies of modules).

My current tsconfig-options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "System",
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "outDir": "src/scripts/js"
  }
```

I left the example config of intern almost untouched, though I added the angular-modules as in the official angular example tests.
Any hints or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [loaders configuration](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader). It shows how you can use RequireJS instead of the Dojo loader. If SystemJS provides the same API (AMD), you should be able to swap that in as well.

Comment: The SystemJS provides an AMD like interface through System.amdDefine() and System.amdRequire(). But I have the same trouble making the bridge. Look https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#requirejs-support.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is a little self-promoting but *does* answer the question.

SystemJS's AMD support doesn't work with Intern/Dojo's AMD loader plugins.  To that end, I wrote [intern-systemjs-loader](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/intern-systemjs-loader), an adaptor that overrides some of those AMD plugins with SystemJS-compatible solutions.

You can `npm install` it and reference it in the [loaders configuration](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader).  I'm using it to avoid the transpile step for my ES2015+ code, including writing async tests using ES2017's async/await.